# Service worker not working when tested on mobile using local ip

Tags: javascript, android, service-worker

Im having an issue with Service worker.

The Service worker works fine, when I it test locally (because it allows http://localhost), but if I have to test the same app on mobile using my computer IP, it pops up an error in the console saying: The Notification API may no longer be used from insecure origins. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
How can I test that the service worker works fine in mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to deploy it somewhere where https is supported. I use [surge](https://surge.sh) or [now](https://zeit.co/now) to do this while I'm developing and testing my application.